# Get information from an api with Angularjs $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have access to a JSON api, the api URL is `http://host/api`, when I ask the api with the following parameters

```
http://host/api&q=count_people&on=house&house_id=123433
```

the api response is:

```
{
    people: "6"
}
```

the api works like the previous example, now when I trying to use in my controller i have the following code

```
//app.js
var app = app.module('myapp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('API', function($resource) {
    var API = $resource('host/api');

    return {
      get: function(o, q, params) {
        s = API.get({on: o, q: q, house_id: params.id}, function(u) {
          return u;
        })
        return s;
      }
    };
});

app.controller('myController', function($scope, API) {
  $scope.ns = {
    count_people: function() {
      return API.get('house', 'count_people', {id: 123433});
    }
  };
});
```

in my template i have

```
<!-- mytemplate.html -->
<p>Total of people in house: {{ns.count_people().people}}</p>
```

but the `ns.count_people().people` **never is called**

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: I don't see a callback.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne can you explain

Comment: `Resource.get([parameters], [success], [error])` Where `[success]` is the function to execute when the request is successful.  This is where the object containing people would be, and from there you would need to return it or set something in scope to its value in order to use it in the template.  I don't know coffee too well, but I don't see that happening

Comment: @TheSharpieOne is coffeescript see the `->` that is the callback, i0m going to parse to javascript

Comment: Your script must have been cut off.  I don't see `->` in the params passed `API.get`.

Comment: `count_people: (id)` takes an id, you need to call it with an id `ns.count_people(123433).people`

Comment: @sza my mistake when I write the question

Comment: Nvm I see that your not using ngResource down in the controller where you call API.get, you are overriding it in the factory.  In that case, the URL it generates will not be the one you specified. params: params would put &params={id:id} instead of &house_id=id

Comment: q will be URI encoded, the `&`'s you add will be encoded.  You will want to extend/combine those objects to create the parameters you pass.

Comment: I'm really more interested in why not run the function

Comment: Oh, its getting called.  The problem appears to be that it is getting called over and over and over and over.  I made a fiddle with your code and it kept trying to call the API.

Comment: @TheSharpieOne i'update the question again avoiding the params topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do what you want to do would need to be in two steps.  Get the data, display the data.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/He9cc/3/
(Note: The API end point does not return anything, but you can see its being called. Once.)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('API', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/host/api/');
});

app.controller('myController', function ($scope, API) {
    $scope.ns = {
        count_people: function (id) {
            API.get({on:"house",q:"count_people",house_id:id}, function(data){
                $scope.ns.people[id] = data.people
            });
        },
        people: []
    };
});
```

HTML has the extra set of init to get the count from the API

```
<p ng-init='ns.count_people(212321)'>Total of people in house: {{ns.people[212321]}}</p>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer the `ng-init` did not work for me, but i replace for other thing